# SQL Server 2014 Import Wizard missing data source option

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ms-access, import, odbc

I have already run the upsizing wizard from my production Access 2010 .accdb database to create all the table structures and move the data on to our new SQL Server 2014. This included adding some PKs on the server which didn't exist in Access and some other clean up.

I have duplicated all the table structures to create a development version of the tables in their own database on the same server and am now trying to pull the data from the development version of the .accdb into the development database. (i.e., I don't want to run the Upsizing Wizard again from the Dev Access DB because of all the structure clean up that I don't want to do again.)

Using `Right-click | Tasks | Import Data` to get the `Import and Export Wizard`, when I click the drop down on Data source, I have an option for `Microsoft Access (Microsoft Jet Database Engine)` which doesn't recognize the `.accdb` format.

I've seen screen shots from various places on the web of the Import Wizard with a `Microsoft Access (Microsoft Access Database Engine)` option which does recognize the `.accdb` format.

Why would my `Import Wizard` be missing this data source option, and what can I do to resolve that?

---

Based on Aaron's suggestions, I checked the ODBC driver, and it appears to be the 64-bit version:
[image]

If I explicitly run `c:\windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe`, I get what must be the 32-bit version:
[image]

I'm running 64-bit Office on a 64-bit Win7 installation, and I'd assume that SQL Server 2014 is 64-bit by default (I didn't install the server nor the SSMS on my machine).

It seems that the [initial link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134827/how-do-i-use-a-32-bit-odbc-driver-on-64-bit-server-2008-when-the-installer-doesn) Aaron provided addresses the exact opposite of what I'm trying to accomplish. That issue seems to be trying to explicitly use the 32-bit driver on a 64-bit system, while I seem to be stumbling into the 32-bit driver when I want the 64-bit. It does seem that there may be something wrong in the registry, as that question mentions, but I'm not comfortable enough to root around in there on my own, though I can certainly follow some instructions.

Comment: Is it possible you only have the 64-bit drivers installed, and need the 32-bit ones to work with Access?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - entirely. Where would I go to confirm this, and to find the 32-bit drivers if that is the issue?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1134827/how-do-i-use-a-32-bit-odbc-driver-on-64-bit-server-2008-when-the-installer-doesn), [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181099.aspx) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2011/03/31/32-and-64-bit-connectivity-from-the-same-machine.aspx).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, thanks for your suggestions. I've looked at those links and they've caused more questions than answers. I've updated the OP with some additional info.

Comment: Sorry, really don't know. Last time I touched Access was I think Access 97.

Comment: Not an answer but a workaround. From access you could attach the tables in sql and write an append query to push the data into sql.

Comment: I ended up dropping the tables, re-running the upsizing wizard, then scripting all the indices from the prod tables and running the script in dev. There's got to be a better way, and @Peter hit on a better solution, but I'm still curious why SQL Server won't find the 64-bit based ODBC connection option.